# How to insert an unique confirmation code into an email from php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a MySQL database with students. I have the functionality to select some or all of them and send emails to the selected.

I also can save the emails in a table in the database. I now need a way, when I send an email to selected students, to insert in the body of the email an unique link, that, when they click on it, changes their status from, lets say approved, to confirmed, on the backend, while they see a message that their request has been confirmed.

The code I have right now that works for sending mails and inserting them in the DB is this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $page_name = 'Send Emails';
        require_once('header.php');
        if(!empty($_POST['send'])){
            $id_mail= "";
            foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $key => $value) {
                echo "$key - $value <br>";
                $id_mail .= "$value, ";
                }
                $id_mail= substr($id_mail, 0, -2);
            }
        if(!empty($_POST['Send2'])){
                 $mail= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT student_id, mail FROM students WHERE student_id IN($_POST[id_mail])"); 
            echo "SELECT student_id, mail FROM students WHERE student_id IN($_POST[id_mail]) "; 
             while ($row_mail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mail)) { 
                 echo "$row_mail[mail] "; 
             $to = $row_mail['mail']; 
             $subject = $_POST['head']; 
             $message = $_POST['body']; 
             $headers = 'From: code-week@example.com' . "\r\n" . 
            'Please do not reply to this message' . "\r\n" . 
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
             mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
             $sent_mails= mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO sent_mails (id_st, mail_head, content) VALUES ('$_POST[id_mail]', '$subject', '$message') "); 
             if (mysqli_query($conn, $sent_mails)){ 
                echo "Success"; 
             } else { 
            echo "Error ". $sent_mails . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
            } 
          } 
       } 
        mysqli_close($conn); 
 ?> 
    <form name='mail2' method='post' action='send_email.php'><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_mail" value="<?php echo $id_mail; ?>">
        <br/>

    <input type='text' name='head' placeholder='header'>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <textarea name='body' rows="4" cols="50" placeholder='body'></textarea><br/>
    <br/>
    <input class='btn btn-danger'type='submit' name="Send2" value='Send'>
    </form>
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: @Epodax Couldn't agree more. What do you need buddy?

Comment: I need a way to insert in the body of the email a unique link, that, when they click on it, changes their status from, lets say approved, to confirmed, on the backend, while they see a message that their request has been confirmed. Basically an RSVP system. I invite someone via email to participate, if he decides to join, he clicks the link I sent him to RSVP.

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a link in the email, so that the receiver proves that it is his email address (something like `http://www.example.com/confirmEmailAddress?randomCode=abcdef`), correct?
Well, this random code would not have to be unique if you added the receiver's email address or his unique database ID in the link as well:
`http://www.example.com/confirmEmailAddress?NotNecessarilyUniqueRandomCode=abcdef&email=john.doe@example.com`
You would then just have to check your database against both columns.

Comment: No, I know it is his email. The email I am sending is to tell the person he is invited to an event he signed up for, and the link is supposed to be his confirmation that he will be attending. I have a table with people's statuses. When they are sent an email, their status becomes 'approved'. The idea is to send them a link, and when they click it, the status is changed to 'confirmed'.

Comment: I see, but why would you need a unique ID then? Can't the link simply be something like `href=http://www.example.com/?action=participationUpdate&eventID=<?php echo $id_event; ?>&studentID=<?php echo $id_student; ?>&newStatus=confirmed`? (Still, you could combine such a link with the little extra security mentioned above, so that one student does not know the link to confirm the participation of another student.)